# High CPU utilization on Azure continuous WebJob running single process multi-threaded .NET application

Tags: .net, multithreading, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

Background-

I have a .NET application that runs as a single multi-threaded process within an Azure App Service Continuous WebJob.  The application has threads that (1)connect it to a REST API and pulls back data which is stored in an Azure SQL database, (2)requests data from the SQL database, does some calculations, then stores the results, (3)pulls additional data, compares it to a rule sent and sends email notifications using SendGrid SMTP and text messages using Twilio.

This application runs fine as a scheduled task on a virtual Windows Server 2016 Standard [which also hosts the SQL (2016 Standard) database] with 8 cores and 8 GB of RAM consuming only 0-15% of CPU and only about 100MB of RAM.

Issue-

After moving it to a continuous Azure WebJob (Standard S1 tier) connected to Azure SQL (Standard S20 tier) and starting the service, CPU went to 100% for both SQL and the App Service.  Upgraded the App Service to P2V2 tier and the database to P1 tier and CPU is manageable at about 60% for the App Service and 70% for SQL, but still much higher than expected.

Has anyone experienced this?  Does anyone know of threading limits or Azure ability to handle complex applications in a WebJob?  Suggestions on what to look at?  Can't figure out why so many more resources would be needed in Azure as compared to a VM.  Wanted to try and go serverless for the flexibility and scalability.

There are no errors being thrown and the application runs fine, but would like to add additional functionality to the application but concerned about consuming more resources.

Comment: That *is* normally the expected behavior of a "multi-threaded process".  The more threads you use, the more work it can get done.  That it doesn't burn 100% core in the test case is because it gets bogged down on waiting on I/O, like that SQL server and REST service.  Networking is slow.  By moving it, you probably now cut down on the networking overhead.  No more slow Internet routers in between and the speed of light is no longer a factor.  This is highly desirable, you'll need less threads.

Comment: Thanks.  Did find that the app service and the database were in 2 "different" locations so the app/database communication was going over different networks.  One was US East and the other was US East 2.  Put them both in US East and it cut the app service utilization in half.  It's still higher than we'd expect, but much better.  Unfortunately this provided no improvement to the SQL CPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

Application performance issues often have no obvious explanation and demand deep inspection and analysis accounting for more factors than you can describe in writing.

Your best bet it to use Application Insights to see if these can give you a helping hand.

What I will say is that SQL performance is throttled by number of DTUs, whereas your local instance wouldn't be.  And your CPU coming down after scaling up the App Service Plan tier from S1 to P2V2 simply indicates that your service plan isn't as performant as your local server, or that you have other applications running in your service plan which are causing resource contention.

There's a good article on troubleshooting performance issues with Application Insights here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-performance

Comment: Thanks.  Took a look at Application Insights and unfortunately I guess the way the application is structured I don't get much detail about what is going on inside.  Basically have one /GET request that shows in there getting called over and over (as it should).